# HTML 5 strange img always adds 3px margin at bottom

Tags: css, html

When I change my website to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Every img element that is wrapped inside a DIV has a 3px bottom margin to it even though that margin is not defined in CSS. In other words, there are no style attributes that are causing that 3px bottom margin.

```
<div class="placeholder">
    <img alt="" src="/haha.jpg" />
</div>
```

Now let's say haha.jpg is 50x50, and .placeholder is set to display: table. Strangely the height dimensions of .placeholder in my observation is 50x53...

Has anyone encountered this anomaly before and fixed it?

## EDIT

Here is the JS FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/fRpK6/

Comment: This is why you should use a Reset CSS.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net as an example? include some relevant css you have?

Comment: @JamesKhoury added jsfiddle, notice how .placeholder having black background does not fit the height of the img correctly.

Comment: @xbonez I do have a reset.css, it's irrelevant, check the JS fiddle

Comment: Sorry, missed the HTML5 in the title.

Comment: Equivalent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image (There are probably others)

Comment: I have the same problem with 'inline-block' wrapped with 'block' element. vertical-align: middle; - for 'inline-block' is working solution for that case.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

This problem is caused by the image behaving like a character of text (and so leaving a space below it where the hanging part of a "y" or "g" would go), and is solved by using the `vertical-align` CSS property to indicate that no such space is needed.  Almost any value of `vertical-align` will do; I'm fond of `middle`, personally.

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fRpK6/1/

Comment: The problem is caused by `vertical-align: baseline`, which is the default for most elements and indicates that that space should be reserved.  Some of the other legal values for `vertical-align` also reserve this space, but `top`, `text-top`, `middle`, `bottom` and `text-bottom` do not.  `sub` also doesn't appear to, but I'm leery of trusting that one.

Comment: If the image is smaller than your font size, then this won't work, because the div will still reserve enough space for text even if it isn't reserving that "special" space.  In that case, you'll have to use either pantryfight's suggestion or `display: block` to remove the text from the picture entirely.

Comment: Also applies to iframe (e.g., for embedded youtube videos or google maps)

Comment: 2021 and still the best answer!

Answer (score 26):

I often solve this by giving the image element `display:block` or `display:inline-block` as appropriate.

Comment: Images are `display:inline-block` by default; that won't do anything.

Comment: Actually, this solves the issue for some reason with HTML5. Like described also [here](http://my-tech-explorations.blogspot.fi/2012/05/html5-image-padding-issue.html), +1

Comment: no, they are `display:inline`, or more technically a "replaced inline element"

Comment: @SpliFF Okay, yes, you're right; it acts somewhat like `inline-block`, but it isn't the same thing, and actually setting it to `inline-block` does have some effect.  (I thought I should formally acknowledge that, so your comment stops accumulating upvotes.)

Comment: `display: inline-block` can't fulfill it~

Comment: `display:block` is good. But `display:inline-block` does NOT work.

Answer (score 7):

it is solved my problem.

```
line-height: 0;
```

Comment: This is roughly equivalent to `font-size: 0px;`, mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe setting

```
line-height: 1;
```

on the image will also fix this problem, especially if it's in a block by itself.

Answer (score 2):

apply `display: block` to the image fix it, i have this issue with images inside floated divs.

Answer (score 2):

maybe it is the problem of the white-space that causes this.
so, the methods bellow maybe useful

```
img {
display: block;
```

}
or

```
img {
vertical-align: top/middle/...;
```

}

or

```
.placeholder {
font-size: 0;
```

}

Comment: how does this improve on the other answers that are already posted?

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a combination of

```
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0;
```

on the wrapping container that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact explanation of why it happens, but give your placeholder div font-size: 0px;

```
.placeholder {
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

Comment: yes but it's ridiculous. you're still asking the browser to treat the image as a text character and if you want to add other elements inside it they will inherit the 0px font size.

Answer (score 1):

In my special case none of the above solutions worked.

I had a wrapping `div` with `display: flex;`.

I managed to make this working by adding: `align-items: flex-start;` to the wrapping div AND to all the images: `display: block;`.

Before I explicitly told the content to align it messed up the Layout. After setting it to flex-start everything works like a charm.

Comment: Were you using a flexbox with `flex-direction: column` and a fixed height?  That would put a margin between the images (but not below the last one) for a completely different reason.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what's the exact problem but i have try this with 2 different option first apply class on img tag this will work and second apply font size 0 px;

http://jsfiddle.net/fRpK6/3/

Comment: `display: table`?  It works; it isn't really cross-browser, but I think it works on all of the browsers that this problem occurs on.  Hmm, I guess I'll compile a list of values for `display` that fix the problem... `block`, `list-item`, `table`, and any of the 8 `table-*` values, though you'd have to be insane to use most of them.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens with piled up `divs`, just add `float` property.
Example:

```
<body>
  <div class="piledUpDiv">Some text</div>
  <div class="piledUpDiv">Some text</div>
  <div class="piledUpDiv">Some text</div>
</body>
```

Problematic CSS:

```
.piledUpDiv{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;   
 }
```

Solution:

```
.piledUpDiv{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left; 
 }
```

Comment: `float` overrides `display`.  It's a different way of aligning things, and could potentially cause quite a mess if you don't specifically want float behavior.