# Remove space between table cells

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with 2 cells and `<img>` inside both.

I tried to use `cellspacing:0` and `cellpadding:0`, `valign="top"`, but none of them seem to solve my problem, I still have this annoying space between my cells. how can I solve this problem

Here's my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gbumubn3/

Comment: use `font-size:0px` on your `<tr>`tag that should remove the space

Comment: I thinks its big time you have to move from tables to divs.

Comment: @Cherry it's a newsletter that i have to support for old browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is actually caused by the `<img>` tag. Take a look at this jsfiddle (I've added a red border to the table cells): http://jsfiddle.net/gbumubn3/13/

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844318/1024766) answer for more details.

> This problem is caused by the image behaving like a character of text (and so leaving a space below it where the hanging part of a "y" or "g" would go), and is solved by using the vertical-align CSS property to indicate that no such space is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The white space is because of the `<img>` not the `<table>` element. Because of it's display mode it's behaving like text and reserving some space for 'Descenders' which are the low-hanging parts of text for example the bottom part of a lower case 'y'.

For more on a 'descender': [Typography Descenders, on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)

### The basic solution:

The solution is to set the CSS style `display:block` on your `<img>` elements.

### The 'elegant' solution:

You can implement a CSS rule to automatically set `display:block` on all images who are the only child of a table's `<td>` element:

```
td img:only-child {display:block}
```

*Edit: You can also use the CSS attribute `vertical-align` to solve this issue whilst preserving `display:inline-block`.*

### Forked example:

[**Click here for JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qkvd3mhr/)

Comment: I like the `display:block` fix. It seems like a more logical fix than a vertical alignment. By the way, the default display for images is `inline-block`, not the `inline` that you implied.