# CSS: not exact vertical align in table

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I find that if I put an image inside a table cell like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91beLce7/1/)):

```
<table style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid black">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://www.google.com.hk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There will be a small space below the image, making the vertical align not exact:

[image]
[image]

Does any one know what is happening here?

I tried to add `vertical-align: middle` to the `td`, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML 5 strange img always adds 3px margin at bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844205/html-5-strange-img-always-adds-3px-margin-at-bottom). In particular look at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10844318/3400962](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10844318/3400962) for the reason why this is happening and the way to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding `display: block` to the `img` element? Seems to fix most problems for things within tables.

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid black">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://www.google.com.hk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91beLce7/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the img as "display:block"

```
img {display:block}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/91beLce7/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/91beLce7/5/)

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table tr td img{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that with `line-height: .8em;`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/91beLce7/6/)**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table {
    background:red;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
tr {
    background:#ccc;
}
img {
    background:green;
    display: block;
}
```