# Link is not the same height as child elements

Tags: html, css

I have an item which has 2 child elements, one is a container for text and the other one is an image. After the item there is a blank space. I used inspect element and that spaces belongs to the link, but to me ii doesn't make sense. I am new to web development so please don't be hard on me.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/semfa64e/
This is a mobile first design so you should probably make the result window smaller.

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="item-content">
            <h3>Item title</h3>
            <p>Item description lorem ipsum dolor sit amet contrectetur</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" alt="img" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="item-content">
            <h3>Item title</h3>
            <p>Item description lorem ipsum dolor sit amet contrectetur</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" alt="img" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.item-content {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover .item-content {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 20%;
    background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, .7);
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: `<a>` is a `inline` element so ... add `display: block;` to `<a>` to change its default setting

Comment: I did try that but it does nothing.

Comment: @LeonLaci  What space are you concerned about?

Comment: The space below the item.

Comment: so the small white space between the pictures?  Do you want two of the same pictures and you're concerned about the white space in between them?  Or the space in between the semi transparent divs?

Comment: The space between 2 pictures. i.e. The space below the picture.

Comment: @LeonLaci I update a answer about why cause this problem :D you can have a check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<a>` there's some blank (space) inside it and a blank has a `4px` height and width in chrome...

So what causes this problem? 
`<img>` is called `replaced element`, it'll be replaced by the data (binary) so it basically behaves like a text and lets the block have extra height.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements

1. Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `<img>`
2. Add `display: block;` to `<img>`
3. Add `display: flex;` to `<a>`

reference:

1. https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
2. [HTML 5 strange img always adds 3px margin at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844205/html-5-strange-img-always-adds-3px-margin-at-bottom)

Comment: Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `<img>`
Thanks although i had a somewhat different problem but this suggestion seemed to put me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

add `display: block;` to your img-tag

Answer (score 0):

It is not about `<a>` tag it's about `<img>` tag. You need to add `img { max-width: 100%; display: block; }` for responsiveness.