# Unwanted padding in html table gmail signature

Tags: html-table, html-email

I'm building an html signature for myself.
I want to achieve an overlaping td element with an background and an image.
I couldn't get it working so I decided to use an image with background to achieve that.

What I got:

GMAIL

[image]

(The [image](http://fernandocandiani.com.br/email/fernandocandiani@133.png) is smaller than the container and has a partial background)

There is an unwanted padding (3px) between the td and img tag.

BROWSER

[image]

Code:

```
<table width="363" height="130" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="none" >
<tr>
    <!-- This row is needed to enforce col widths in Outlook -->
    <td width="40">
    </td>
    <td width="3">
    </td>
    <td width="10">
    </td>
    <td width="100">
    </td>
    <td width="10">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="40" valign="middle" height="130" colspan="1" bgcolor="#417dc0" nowrap style="width: 40px; vertical-align: middle; height: 130px; column-span: 1; background-color: #417dc0; white-space: nowrap;">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;text-align: center;">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fernando.n.candiani" target="_blank"><img src="http://fernandocandiani.com.br/email/facebook.png" width="20" height="20"></a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;text-align: center;">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/fernandocandiani" target="_blank"><img src="http://fernandocandiani.com.br/email/linkedin.png" width="20" height="20"></a>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/110769302461961049884" target="_blank"><img src="http://fernandocandiani.com.br/email/googleplus.png" width="20" height="20"></a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="3" valign="middle" colspan="1" height="130" bgcolor="#417dc0" nowrap style="width: 3px; vertical-align: middle; height: 130px; column-span: 1; background-color: #417dc0; white-space: nowrap;">
        <div style="border-right:2px solid #ffffff;height:100px"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="10" valign="middle" colspan="1" height="130" bgcolor="#417dc0" nowrap style="width: 10px; vertical-align: middle; height: 130px; column-span: 1; background-color: #417dc0; white-space: nowrap;">
    </td>
    <td width="100" valign="middle" height="130" colspan="1" bgcolor="#ffffff" nowrap style="width: 85px; vertical-align: middle; height: 130px; column-span: 1; background-color: #ffffff; white-space: nowrap;">
        <img width="100" height="130" src="http://fernandocandiani.com.br/email/fernandocandiani@133.png">
    </td>
    <td width="10" valign="middle" colspan="1" height="130" bgcolor="#ffffff" nowrap style="width: 10px; vertical-align: middle; height: 130px; column-span: 1; background-color: #ffffff; white-space: nowrap;">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Tried many approaches and couldn't get it working.

PS: It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Opera when rendered straight in browser, but when pasted to gmail signature it adds the 3px padding/margin

EDIT:
I don't if it is worth mentioning but the table has 133px height and the image has 130px as the code says. The table should has 130px by code as well. If I increase the image to 133px the table goes to 136px and so on.

Comment: maybe img has padding or border.. set border to none and padding to 0 and see

Comment: No luck! I don't if it is worth mentioning but the table has 133px height and the image has 130px as the code says. The table should has 130px by code as well. If I increase the image to 133px the table goes to 136px and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display: block or display: inline-block;

This is a known bug that was unknown to me!
The 3px gap -> [HTML 5 strange img always adds 3px margin at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844205/html-5-strange-img-always-adds-3px-margin-at-bottom)