# html canvas position woe

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I try to overlay a `canvas` exactly on top of a 256px by 256px image (of 8x8 grids) and draw an 8x8 black square --

```js
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    canvas.width = 1024;
    canvas.height = 1024;
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 8, 8);
```

```css
    #wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 256px;
    }
    
    #img {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    #canvas {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
      top: -256px;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <img id="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/0qjIa89.png" />
          <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

However, I don't understand why the black square drawn is slightly offset down relative to the grid image --

[image]

complete jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ze8ufqcv/7/

How to position the canvas drawing *exactly* on top of the image?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ze8ufqcv/11/  add   display: block; to image

Comment: Thanks @"Fast Snail", that's really _fast_. If you care to put it in the answer with a simple explanation of how "display: block;" does the trick (as oppose to the default "display: inline;" I guess) I'd be more than happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add display: block;  to your `#img` selector.

Like this .

```
#img {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, however, I'd much appreciate if someone can explain why "display: block;" for img actually shifts the canvas a few pixels up

Comment: I don't know the exact reason , when i have extra spacing problem i will do like this.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to the `img` having a `vertical-align: baseline` which causes 3px space to be added at the bottom. 
You can remove this by adding `vertical align: middle` to the `img`.
Since `vertical-align` doesn't apply to block-level elements, `display:block` does the job as well.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 1024;
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.fillRect(0, 0, 8, 8);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 256px;
}

#img {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*or display: block*/
  /* not necessary
  top: 0;
  left: 0; */
}

#canvas {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  top: -256px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img id="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/0qjIa89.png" />
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Found a better explanation which you can refer to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844205/html-5-strange-img-always-adds-3px-margin-at-bottom/10844318

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I wish I can accept your answer as well or have enough reputation to up vote it

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not shifting the image a few pixels down, but actually eliminating the gap between the initial position of the two elements. You can see this by leaving out the `top: -256px;` and you'll find a few pixels space in between the image and your canvas. This is eliminated by adding the `display:block;` .

An alternative would be setting the wrapper to `position:relative;` and the canvas to `position:absolute;` and deleting the top offset.