# unwanted space in css boxes

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove white space below image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

I have this page [HERE](http://www.kimwilddesigns.com/index_new.htm). All four boxes with the images (one long horizontal and 3 smaller ones at the bottom) all have empty space below the image and above the bottom border. If I make these boxes have a pixel height it goes away but I need to leave it at auto because its a responsive site (work in progress). I cannot figure out what I'm missing. Any suggestions would be great!

CSS is [HERE](http://www.kimwilddesigns.com/css/kw_styles-responsive.css)

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the images inside those boxes to:

```
display: block
```

That should solve it.

Comment: +1 This is for sure the correct answer