# How to force image to have even height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let me explain this question. I'm working on a responsive website that need the image to be scaled depending on the window's width. Do I have all set those image with this style

```
.bgImg{width:100%; height:auto; display:block; position:relative;}
```

and I have make a 3 column group like this

[image]

the thing is when the height of the window becomes odd, both 25% column have now a margin of 1px at the bottom

[image]

You'll need to zoom in the image above since it's only 1px.

I was wondering if there's a way to fix this or any javascript that could force the image height to round up to the nearest even number so all my image's height will be even and will fix that problem.

**Added a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2QneE/3/**

Comment: Have you checked this is not it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image

Comment: No this is really because the middle column height is even and now both 1st and 3rd are odd that cause this problem. If the window height is even, the problem is not occurring. And my image is display:block too.

Comment: Can you recreate this on jsfiddle?

Comment: I've set up something similar, and I can't recreate it: http://jsfiddle.net/2QneE/

Comment: @Shmiddty Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2QneE/3/ Now notice the red 1px margin at the bottom when you change the window's width

Comment: Does your CSS include a set of browser reset rules?