# Extra space in my figure

Tags: jquery, html, css, space

I've got a problem here, I created a figure with 10/1 ratio and it should be the exact same space than my img (who's real size is 4000*/400* thus 10/1 ratio as well) but I have an extra space poping out of nowhere.

Do you know where it comes from ?

Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/21/

```
<figure class="container">                  
    <img class="content" src="http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/6766/sampes.jpg" alt="sample" />
</figure>

* 
{
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
border:0
}

.container
{
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
.content
{
    width:100%
}


var $cont = $('.container .content'),
    init_size = $cont.width()*0.1,
    c =0,
    s = [400,init_size];

$cont.height( init_size );

$cont.click(function(){   
  $(this).stop().animate({height: s[c++%2] });
});
```

edit: it seems that the problem come from the fact that I call 2 class in my jquery but I still dont know why, the ratio is still the same.

Comment: What extra space? Do you mean the black line at the bottom?

Comment: @isherwood Yes exactly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove white space below image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are displayed inline by default, and space is left for character descenders per line-height.

http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/22/

```
.content {
    display: block;
}
```