# How to remove space under images?

Tags: html, css

So here's my problem, there's a small white space showing up under the pictures on my tumblr, but the space only shows up under photosets, not under photos.

I have on my CSS:

```
#post{padding:10px;}
#post img{display:block;}
```

And then on my html:

```
{block:Posts}
<div id="post">
{block:Photo}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}"/>{/block:Photo}
{block:Photoset}{Photoset-500}{/block:Photoset}
</div>
{/block:Posts}
```

But the photoset adds a 3px space under the images, turning the padding to 13px for no reason. Can someone help me figure out this?

Comment: This isn't html. Is this some sort of tumblr script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove white space below image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

Comment: This is html. It's tumblr html, but still html.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. Tumblr system works differently.

Comment: No it's not. But even still, you just asked the same question 27minutes ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599731/remove-space-under-images

Comment: You need to change that - when you say "and then my html" -- that's certainly not HTML

Comment: Yes, it is html. And yes, I asked it already, but they told me I shouldn't post links, so I posted only the html on this one.

Comment: This IS html. What do you read at the top of this page? http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qt5l.png "HTML"

Comment: You can't target the photos inside the photoset with css, because they are loaded by tumblr within an iframe.

Comment: So there's no way of fixing this?

Comment: It maybe possible to fix, but you would have to link to a live example of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
img {
display:block;
}
```

should fix it

Comment: Yes...but you have used an ID tag `#` so that setting will not apply to all images.

Comment: Yes, but I already did with all the images. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Then give us a link to your site. Clearly something else is going on

Comment: The spaces are different under the first post and the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
.post{line-height:0;}
```

I had the same issue and this solved it.
Basically, the parent of the img tag needs to have the line-height set to 0.