# vertically align css element closer to image

Tags: php, css

I have a page which serves up random images. below the image is a css element that allows you to vote the image up or down, however, i think the css is a little too below the image. i want it to be vertically closer to the image. can you help?

style.css:

```
.vot_updown2 {
 position:relative;
 margin:3px;
 width:160px;
 background:#ffffff;
 border:0px solid #ffffff;
 font-family:"Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
 text-align:center;
 padding:2px 1px;
 box-shadow:.17em .2em .23em #ffffff;
 -webkit-box-shadow:.17em .2em .23em #ffffff;
 -moz-border-radius:.7em;
 -webkit-border-radius:.7em;
 -khtml-border-radius:.7em;
 border-radius:.7em;
}
```

randimg.php snippet:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<p>", "<div class='tagtext'>AUTHOR: ", ($row['username']), " ", "TAG: ", ($row['tag']), "</div>";
        echo "<p>", '<img src="' . $row['image'] . '" alt="" />', "<br>";

echo "<div class='vot_updown2' id=" . 'vt_' .$table.($row['id']). "></div>";
    }
```

I have tried removing the line break, to no avail. attempt to use span instead of div fails to display the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p>` tags have default margin values, you can adjust the second `<p>` bottom's margin to bring the `vote_updown2` `<div>` closer to it like so:

add class to the image container ex. `image_container`:

```
echo "<p class='image_container'><img src='" . $row['image'] . "' alt='' /></p>";
```

then add css property to the container and adjust the bottom margin as desired:

```
.image_container
{
    margin-bottom: 0; //adjust as required
}
```

[js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/Hq9an/)

Comment: hi razzak, i got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in....

Comment: yah my mistake, you should use single quote inside double quotes `" 'text' "` or escape the double quote by using backslash `" \"text\" "` otherwise the string will break.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .vot_updown2:

```
   margin-top:-10px;
```

You can change the 10px to

Everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the extra white space below the image by giving the img element a "display:block" or "float:left" style declaration. See [Remove white space below image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

**vertical-align:middle;**