# Why is -webkit-margin-before (and after, start, end) not being overridden by my explicit margin and padding rule?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I have:

```
html body nav figure {   /* just to clear specificity doubts  */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I inspect element in chrome, and my rules are applied, but also the following from the user agent stylesheet:

```
figure {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 40px;
}
```

I thought these should be overridden... my rules are not overridden either (not crossed out)

How should I override them?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it.

The rule specified by the user gets applied, and webkit renders margin according to it, "overriding" the default -webkit ones in some way.

The space that I was seeing was from the img not being displayed as block, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image) for more about it.