# Wordpress/HTML - How to add images with NO spaces in between

Tags: html, wordpress, spacing

I'm trying to add several images on my wordpress page but I don't want any spaces in between all of the images.  All of them stacked on top of another..trying to create one big vertically inclined image but all of them have a white line or space in between.

I've tried the following:

No spaced between the tags:

```
<img src="http://www.test.com/images/packages/unnamed (1).jpg"></img><img src="http://www.test.com/images/packages/unnamed.jpg"></img>
```

I read this in another post on here:

```
<div>
    <img border="0" src="http://www.test.com/images/packages/unnamed (1).jpg">
</div><div>
    <img border="0" src="http://www.test.com/images/packages/unnamed.jpg">
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7774854/2126792

Answer (score 0):

you might need to play with the margins/ border with a little css. Both can add space between anything.

Example for your code:

you will need to do a couple things:

1) make the images part of a css class (lets call it noBorder)

ex:

```
<img src="file" class="noBorder" >
```

you will add this class to all of your image tags

2) make the actual class

pretty much like this:

```
<head>
<other head tags>

<style>
    .noBorder{
        margin:0px;
        border:0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

3) alternatively, you could just insert this inline code to each of your image tags:

```
style="border:0px;margin:0px;"
```

ex:

```
<img src="file" style="border:0px;margin:0px;" >
```

note that these styles will also work on those divs you have there

A great resource for these things is: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

and on this subject: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it fixed, thanks for the help.

All I did was this code for all of the images one after another and boom fixed.

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/images/packages/unnamed (1).jpg" style="display:block"></a>
```