# Why does a simple image get a margin-bottom c.q. output space under the image?

Tags: css, image, margin

Please have a look at [this simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6uLbsry/). It contains the following code:

```
<div style="background:yellow; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="http://www.wedesoft.de/test/test.png" />
</div>
```

As you can see, this will output a space under the image so that you can see the yellow colored container. I do not know why, because no space was defined.

Can somebody tell me what is going on please?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image or [Remove white space below image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason

```
display:block;
```

solves this problem as you can see in the accepted answer here:
[Remove white space below image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

Is still do not know why...

Answer (score 3):

An image is an `inline` element. That means it is treated as text. Text has a `line-height`.  The `line-height` is what is causing the space at the bottom. There are multiple ways to solve this.

The following are my favorites:

```
div {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

By setting `line-height` to 0, the space goes away.

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

By making the image a `block` element, it's no longer considered text, thus, `line-height` isn't applicable anymore.

---

As Marc Audet stated in the comments, another way to solve this would be by using `vertical-align`.

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It doesn't matter whether you use `top` or `bottom`.

Comment: You may want to mention that applying `vertical-align: top or bottom` also fixes the problem.

Comment: @Danko Removing the `inline-block` won't solve the problem, since the image will remain `inline`, which is the cause of the problem. You can open [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6uLbsry/3/) and see that it doesn't change the room at the bottom. @Marc Audet: I'll update my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to the `line-height` attribute; try this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6uLbsry/1/)
Where i just set the line height to 0.

Comment: @user3631654 Make sure to mark an awnser for future visitors ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed `line-height` try this

```html
<div style="background:yellow;display:inline-block;line-height: 0px;">
    <img src="http://www.wedesoft.de/test/test.png">
</div>
```

other way you can apply style `display: block;` to img. like

```html
<div style="background:yellow;display:inline-block;">
    <img src="http://www.wedesoft.de/test/test.png" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

take a look at line-height propety on this web: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

basicly what's happening is that there's some default space on the div so that's why you see the yellow line. Adding `line-height: 0px;` should solve the problem.