# Issues in image opacity in hover state

Tags: html, css

Here is my html and css code for hover state.

Html:

```
<div class="col-3">
               <div class="popular"> <a href="#" ><img src="http://s10.postimg.org/4zqkz9rxl/saina_2.png"/></a></div>

    </div>
```

css:

```
div.col-3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count:3;
    column-gap:10px;
    margin:20px 30px;
}
.popular:hover {
opacity:0.7;
background-color:#FF1493;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7sbw18j0/

When i hover an image, it doesn't show like pink color with opacity.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set background color with opacity and background image in hover state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169488/how-to-set-background-color-with-opacity-and-background-image-in-hover-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="popular"> <a href="#"><img src="http://s10.postimg.org/4zqkz9rxl/saina_2.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.col-3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count:3;
    column-gap:10px;
    margin:20px 30px;
}
.popular {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.popular:hover {
    background:#FF1493;
}
.popular:hover img {
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7sbw18j0/4/)

Comment: somewhat okay @aru. but.. at the bottom of image, it shows pink color border right? How to remove that?

Comment: @selva, sorry for the delay. just add 'vertical-align:middle' to the class '.popular:hover img{vertical-align:middle;}' to get it fixed!! Check the updated demo - http://jsfiddle.net/7sbw18j0/5/

Comment: may i know, why we are using vertical-align:middle?

Comment: hope this helps you...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image   and   http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-remove-white-space-under-an-image-using-css.php

Answer (score 2):

```css
div.col-3 {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}
.popular {
  background-color: #FF1493; /* added background for parent not image so that the background is visible when hovered */
}
.popular img {
  vertical-align: middle; /* added to remove extra space below */
}
.popular img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7; /* decrease image opacity on hover */
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="popular">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/4zqkz9rxl/saina_2.png" />
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer like this http://s17.postimg.org/q0z3ehtin/Untitled_1.png.. what is this pink color line?

Comment: try settting `div.col-3 ` to `display:inline-block` @selva