# Why is a div that wraps an svg taller than the svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

Apparently svgs are inline by default:

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
}

svg {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg></svg>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <svg style="display:block;"></svg>
</div>
```

Setting `display: block` on the svg, it removes the extra height.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7774854/1650757