# low resolution images appear blurry when width is 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have a div container which is about 600px of width. I'm displaying an image inside this container. I have given the image a `width:100%` and `height:'auto'`. There are no issues in this but when i have to display a small image (Ex:width around 50px),because the width is set to 100% it appears blurry. How can i prevent this from happening? My thought was to however getting the width of the image and if it's lower than let's say 80px, the image width is set to a lower value. Is it the correct approach to do this? Or is there any better way?

My code

```
<div className="home_post_sections">

    <img src={image} className="homepost_image"/>

</div>
```

css

```
.home_post_sections {

    width: 610px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;

}

.homepost_image {

    width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: `width: 100%` would make the image `610px` wide, which would definitely make it blurry. Were you wanting to use `max-width`?

Comment: You shouldn't really stretch an image at all, I would be tempted to try `max-width: 100%;` instead, that way smaller images won't stretch and look bad. Of course, if you have *really big images* they probably won't look great shrunk either

Comment: But i want my div container to fill with the image if it does not affect the resolution much.. I want to set my width to max-width:'100%' only if the image is smaller and will affect the resolution when set to width 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my div container to fill with the image if it does not affect
>   the resolution much.

How much the resolution is affected - how much blur is acceptable - is an opinion. The browser won't make this decision for you.

You can use [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) on the image instead of `width`. That way the image will never be wider than it's native resolution. So an image with a width of 60px, will take up 60px of the container.

You can also add `display: block` to the image to remove the small strip of whitespace at the bottom of the container. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

```css
.home_post_sections {
  width: 610px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
}

.homepost_image {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_post_sections">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/610" class="homepost_image" />
</div>
<div class="home_post_sections">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/60" class="homepost_image" />
</div>
```