# CSS - Remove space between <li> tags

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm new to frontend design, around 2 months. I'm having a problem that I can't remove the white spaces between the HTML li tags

Please take a look at my snippet:

```css
ul {
  width:100%;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:100%;
}

.shop-now {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:-121px;
  background-color:white;
  width:42%;
  height:30%;
}

.shop-now > * {
  display:inline-block;
}

.shop-now > h3 {
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/356x150' />
      <div class='shop-now'>
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <span>Shop Now</span>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/356x150' />
      <div class='shop-now'>
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <span>Shop Now</span>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/356x150' />
      <div class='shop-now'>
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <span>Shop Now</span>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get rid of these space between the HTML li tags.

[image]

How do I do that? Please advise.

Comment: can you try li { margin: 0; }; Hope it works

Comment: margin, padding and border-width are the usual suspects. And for future reference I highly recommend reading about box-sizing so you're ready when you come across another common spacing problem https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp Also, if you haven't encountered it yet, dealing with whitespace below images with display: block https://stackoverflow.com/q/7774814/3377049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the gap is because you are shifting the `.shop-now` div upward 121px, the div will still take the space even though you have shifted its position.

therefore you need absolute positioning, so that it does not take up space.

```css
ul {
  width:100%;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li img{
  display: block;
}

.shop-now {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background-color:white;
  width:42%;
}

.shop-now > * {
  display:inline-block;
}

.shop-now > h3 {
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/356x150' />
      <div class='shop-now'>
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <span>Shop Now</span>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/356x150' />
      <div class='shop-now'>
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <span>Shop Now</span>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/356x150' />
      <div class='shop-now'>
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <span>Shop Now</span>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6pk44dp/), to remove the spacing around the `<li>`, include this style rule

```
li {
   margin: 0
}
```

Hope that helps!