# How to let a img tag fill it's parent node?

Tags: html, css

Now I have this:

```css
.image-container {
  margin: 10px auto !important;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="image-container">
  <img src="https://lasenhorita.github.io/assets/images/hero/low/HERO_SADNESS_H_0001.jpg">
</figure>
```

Under the `img` (image size: 800x520) tag, there is a space I don't know how to remove.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, an image is an inline level element (display: inline-block). All inline level elements have some extra default spacing in all directions (4px). That is why you have this space down there.

All you need to do is to set the image to `display:block.`

You can find the same issues throughout stackoverflow though, so try to maybe google it first if possible.

For example: [Remove white space below image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

Edit: typos

Answer (score 0):

add `display:flex` to `.image-container`

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px auto !important;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="image-container">
  <img src="https://lasenhorita.github.io/assets/images/hero/low/HERO_SADNESS_H_0001.jpg">
</figure>
```